# Website doesn't work under Linux, but works under Windows/Mac

Tags: browser, web

I'm trying to buy a product on https://qinao.de/ with my (Arch) Linux laptop and different Browsers (Chrome, Firefox). But I can't add products to the Cart (and some images don't load).

It works fine on my mobile phone, and on my friends' laptops with Windows and Mac.

I've never seen anything like this. Can anybody with Linux confirm this, and perhaps can decode the error messages on the Developer console? Shouldn't the functioning of a website depend entirely on the browser and not the operating system?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a bug or a dark pattern. `[shop_events_listener] Error in trackViewedProductVariant: a is undefined` in dev tools. Firefox/Linux. Not able to add to cart with Chromium too

Comment: This happened to me a few weeks ago on a job search site: Didn't work on Linux Chromium, worked with Windows Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the functioning of a website depend entirely on the browser and not the operating system?

The website can ask the browser for what operating system it runs on and adjust behaviour accordingly.

Honestly, I think you just found a bug in someone's commercial software (i.e., that website), and they need to fix it.